# How to read value of characteristics?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm currently working on BLE device with CoreBluetooth. I can find my device via `CBCentralManagerDelegate` and connect with my device.

When I want to discover the characteristics of a service, I can get the correct uuid, however, the value of characteristic is `nil`. Any ideas?

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR DISCOVERING CHARACTERISTICS: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    if let characteristics = service.characteristics {

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            print("--------------------------------------------")
            print("Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            print("Characteristic isNotifying: \(characteristic.isNotifying)")
            print("Characteristic properties: \(characteristic.properties)")
            print("Characteristic descriptors: \(characteristic.descriptors)")
            print("Characteristic value: \(characteristic.value)")
        }
    }
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Characteristic UUID: FA01
Characteristic isNotifying: false
Characteristic properties: CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue: 26)
Characteristic descriptors: nil
Characteristic value: nil
```

Another question about properties, according to [Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.com/log-in?btorgReturnURL=%2ftechnical%2fspecifications%2fadopted.htm)

[image]

Why [nRFConnect](https://itunes.apple.com/tw/app/nrf-connect/id1054362403?mt=8) shows up `read`, `write`, `notify`. But it indeed gets the right value of the characteristic.

[image]

Comment: The value will be nil until you issue a read request and get a callback to the `didUpdateValue` CBPeripheralDelegate method.

Comment: Call `func readValue(for characteristic: CBCharacteristic)` when you discovered it. Or setNotify (if available for char).

Comment: It works. how about the properties?

Comment: The characteristic allows for reading, writing, and notification. When you discover the characteristic, these properties are discovered as well. The raw value that is received is 26, which is 16 + 8 + 2 or, written in Hex Code: 0x10 | 0x08 | 0x02, meaning that Read (0x02), Write (0x08) and Notify (0x10) is allowed.

Comment: I am not sure about readValueForCharacter vs setNotify. I was reading temperature data from LM35 on "FFE1" characteristics. On setNotify worked for me but not readValueForCharacteristics....

Answer (score 4):

read value of characteristics. swift 4

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
   for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics!{

            peripheral.readValue(for: newChar)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a bunch!

Comment: greate... @StijnSpijker